# How to consume a web service using PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell, rest, api, web-services

I have the following REST URL:

```
https://webserviceconsume.domain.local/web/api/rest?formatType=json&opName=userAPI&opData={param0:"sample",param1:{"list":[{"name1":"sample1","value1":"sample1"},{"name2":"sample2","value2":"sample2"}]},param2:-1}
```

I want to write a PowerShell script to call this URI. It should basically look like this:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://webserviceconsume.domain.local/web/api/rest' -Body $body -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"
```

Here's the header:

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("accept", 'application/json')
$headers.Add("X-App-Key", 'XXXXX')
```

and then I want to build the `$body` but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below variable as body.

```
$body = [PSCustomObject]@{
    param0 = 'sample';
    param1 =  @{
        list = @(
            @{name1 = "sample1"; value1 = "sample1"};
            @{name2 = "sample2"; value2 = "sample2"}
        )
    };
    param2 = -1
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

Comment: Thanks but as i mentioned to Christy how to prepare the body part from this URL?

Comment: @rora, try the above variable. I hope it is the correct part of the url I took.

Answer (score 1):

Using Rest with PowerShell is a very common thing, [with many blog posts, articles](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20consume%20rest&form=ANSPH1&refig=2649481840f64a838176778ded048a1a&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20consume%20res&sc=3-22&qs=n&sk=&cvid=2649481840f64a838176778ded048a1a),%20and%20[Youtube%20videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell%20consume%20rest%20api) and [Youtube Videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell%20consume%20rest%20api) explaining the topic and showing examples.

[Simple Examples of PowerShell's Invoke-RestMethod](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/invoke-restmethod-powershell-examples)

```
# Simple GET example

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://example.com/api/people'
# assuming the response was in this format { "items": [] }
# we can now extract the child people like this
$people = $response.items

# GET with custom headers example

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("X-DATE", '9/29/2014')
$headers.Add("X-SIGNATURE", '234j123l4kl23j41l23k4j')
$headers.Add("X-API-KEY", 'testuser')

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://example.com/api/people/1' -Headers $headers


# PUT/POST example

$person = @{
    first='joe'
    lastname='doe'
}
$json = $person | ConvertTo-Json
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://example.com/api/people/1' -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json'

# DELETE example

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://example.com/api/people/1' -Method Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

I've only been using PowerShell for 3 days now so this may not be the most efficient code but it's what is working for me

```
$URL        = ""

$Method     = 'PUT'

$Headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$Headers.Add("accept", 'application/json')
$Headers.Add("X-App-Key", 'XXXXX')

$Body       = ""

$Out        = ".\response.json"

    $response = 
    @{
        Uri         = $URL
        Method      = $Method
        Headers     = $Headers
        Body        = $Body
    }
    Invoke-RestMethod @response | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $Out
```

Comment: Thanks but my main concern is preparing Body part from this URL and not the basic structure.